# Appending/Prepending content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a text input. On submit I would like to add the text inside a div named "container". I don't want to completely replace the content inside of the container, because sometimes there will be other elements, and I cannot append/prepend because sometimes there won't be any elements at all. What should I do?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8wh3E/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        var text= $('#text').val();
        // Add the text inside the container
     });
});
```

Comment: Did you even search for "[jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)" or "[jquery prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)"?

Comment: do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/8wh3E/2/

Answer (score 1):

Look at jQuery `append` and `appendTo` http://api.jquery.com/append/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        var text= $('#text').val();

        $('#container').append(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: *"after i click submit, i see the text, then it goes away"*

Comment: Kevin, Surely that is correct because after submit the page will reload unless it was a AJAX POST/GET

Comment: my point was that while this does append the text, it won't actually work because the page reloads, thus making the append pointless. a simple return false or event.preventDefault() would fix it.

Comment: As Steve said, that's expected behavior. If all you want to do is append the text when the value changes, don't link to a form submit method (and in fact, don't include the text field in a form). Instead, register the `append` logic on the input field's `change` handler.